# Ruby - App Academy Practice Exercise About Condition in While Loop

Tags: ruby, while-loop, conditional-statements

I'm completing [App Academy's practice problems](http://prepwork.appacademy.io/coding-test-1/practice-problems/) for the first coding challenge and have a question regarding the solution provided for #8 nearby az:

```
# Write a method that takes a string in and returns true if the letter
# "z" appears within three letters **after** an "a". You may assume
# that the string contains only lowercase letters.
#
# Difficulty: medium.

def nearby_az(string)
  idx1 = 0
  while idx1 < string.length
    if string[idx1] != "a"
      idx1 += 1
      next
    end

    idx2 = idx1 + 1
    while (idx2 < string.length) && (idx2 <= idx1 + 3)
      if string[idx2] == "z"
        return true
      end

      idx2 += 1
    end

    idx1 += 1
  end

  return false
end

# These are tests to check that your code is working. After writing
# your solution, they should all print true.

puts("\nTests for #nearby_az")
puts("===============================================")
    puts('nearby_az("baz") == true: ' + (nearby_az('baz') == true).to_s)
    puts('nearby_az("abz") == true: ' + (nearby_az('abz') == true).to_s)
    puts('nearby_az("abcz") == true: ' + (nearby_az('abcz') == true).to_s)
    puts('nearby_az("a") == false: ' + (nearby_az('a') == false).to_s)
    puts('nearby_az("z") == false: ' + (nearby_az('z') == false).to_s)
    puts('nearby_az("za") == false: ' + (nearby_az('za') == false).to_s)
puts("===============================================")
```

In the second while loop:

```
 while (idx2 < string.length) && (idx2 <= idx1 + 3)
```

why is the condition `(idx2 < string.length)` necessary? I tested the code without it and got the same results.

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Arguably, it's required because the implementation is not very idiomatic Ruby. A more idiomatic method would probably be based on string#split

Answer (score 0):

> why is the condition (`idx2 < string.length`) necessary?

It is not *necessary*. It's a guard to prevent meaningless iterations of the loop, when idx2 goes out of bounds of the string.

Addressing characters at position beyond string's length will return nil. `nil` will never be equal to `'z'`. So we might as well just stop when we reach the end. This is what the check is for here, optimization.

In other situations, out-of-bounds access often is a serious offense and leads to all kinds of problems (crashes, usually). So it makes sense to always do this.

Answer (score 0):

I know this does not answer your exact question, and other people have answered it already, but as the usual case with programming, there's a better way. You can easily solve this with regular expression

```
def nearby_az(string)
  !(string =~ /a\w{0,3}z/).nil?
end
```

The regex will match the pattern `a`, with 0 to 3 characters after it, then a `z`. If this matches nothing, the `=~` operator will return `nil`, so `nil?` method returns `true`, meaning the string does not have nearby az, so we use the `!` to invert the boolean, and this method will return `false`.

If there is a match, `=~` returns the index of the first characters, which is not `nil`, so `nil?` return `false`, and we inverted it as before to return `true`.

Just thought this may be helpful.